# Convert Dataset of array into DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given `Dataset[Array[String]]`.
In fact, this structure has a single field of array type.
Is there any possibility to convert it into a `DataFrame` with each array item placed into a separate column?

If I have `RDD[Array[String]]` I can achieve it in this way:

```
val rdd: RDD[Array[String]] = ???
rdd.map(arr => Row.fromSeq(arr))
```

But surprisingly I cannot do the same with `Dataset[Array[String]]` – it says that there's no encoder for `Row`.

And I cannot replace an array with `Tuple` or `case class` because the size of the array is unknown at compile time.

Comment: Do you get the same exception using ds.toDF?

Comment: which exception? there's no exception thrown in my code sample – it just doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry I meant error, but now realize toDF isn’t what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If arrays have the same size, "select" can be used:

```
val original: Dataset[Array[String]] = Seq(Array("One", "Two"), Array("Three", "Four")).toDS()
val arraySize = original.head.size
val result = original.select(
  (0 until arraySize).map(r => original.col("value").getItem(r)): _*)
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+
|value[0]|value[1]|
+--------+--------+
|One     |Two     |
|Three   |Four    |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do a foldLeft to create all your columns manually.

```
val df = Seq(Array("Hello", "world"), Array("another", "row")).toDS()
```

Then you calculate the size of your array.

```
val size_array = df.first.length
```

Then you add the columns to your dataframe with a foldLeft :

```
0.until(size_array).foldLeft(df){(acc, number) => df.withColumn(s"col$number", $"value".getItem(number))}.show
```

Here our accumulator is our df, and we just add the columns one by one.